# Как заменить все ссылки на одну?

Tags: jquery

У меня на странице много блоков с разными ссылками.
Как мне их заменить, т.е.
нужно чтобы при клике на любую ссылку в блоке переход осуществляся на заданный адрес

Comment: Покажите пример кода и желаемый результат

Comment: @SwaD, серьёзно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.block a').prop('href', '//google.ru')
```